# How to explain this formula : 2b-f(2a-t)=f(t) stating the condition under which the graph of a function is symmetric about the point (a,b)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions

[ Edited. The original question contained a mistake in the formula]

I'm reading a precalculus book telling me that if :

- *f* is a function
- (*a,b*) is a point
- *t* and *2a-t* belong to the domain of *f*

then the grapf of *f* ( or, more precisely, the curve representing *f*) is symmetric relatively to the point (a,b) *iff*

```
                2b-f(2a-t) =  f(t).
```

How to justify this formula analytically?  Also, which intuitive/graphical explanation could be given for this formula ?

Remark. The book I am reading is some sort of AZ to highschool math that gives very few explanations, actually no explanation for the formula in question.

Comment: @MauroAllegranza. Does this  formula f(x-a)=f(-x+a) also apply to central symmetry? My book gives two different formulas for axial symmetry and for central symmetry.

Comment: @ Mauro ALLEGRANZA your formula $f(t)=f(-t)$ deals with curves which are symmetrical with respect to a vertical axis. This is not the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following picture :

[image]

Symmetry can be expressed by the fact that point $(a;b)$ is the midpoint of

$$(a-t,f(a-t)) \ \ \text{and} \ \ (a+t,f(a+t))$$

Thus, the arithmetic mean of the ordinates of these points must be equal to $b$ :

$$\dfrac12 (f(a-t)+f(a+t)) = b  \ \ \ \iff \  \ \ f(a-t)=2b-f(a+t)\tag{1}$$

Setting $T=a-t \ \ \iff \ \ t=a-T$, we can transform (1) into the final relationship :

$$f(T)=2b-f(2a-T)$$

and not $f(T)=2b-f(2a-b)$ as was written.

Comment: @JanMarie. Thanks for your clear answer. Thanks also for indicating the mistake I made in the formula.